# How to rewrite below JSP code in PHP

Tags: php, jsp

I'm new to PHP,  how to write this jsp codes to php ?

```
<table width="1200" height="112" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="251" height="96"><img src="images/head.png" width="251" height="88" alt="Logo" /></td>
      <td width="726" class="right">Customer Support - <a href="contact.php">Contact us</a> | <a href="main.php">Home</a> |
        <% if(session.getAttribute("username")==null) {
            %>
        <a href="login.php">Login</a>
        <%} else {
                %>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        <%}%></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

thanks!

Comment: where is the mysql query?

Comment: Your title says something else and your question is something else !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work for you, because linking to the `login.jsp` or `logout.jsp` inside a php code will be likely to fail. But below code is somewhat equivalent of your jsp code. There is also no mysql query as you've described in title.

```
<?php /*  session_start() should be somewhere here */ ?>
<table width="1200" height="112" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="251" height="96"><img src="images/head.png" width="251" height="88" alt="Logo" /></td>
      <td width="726" class="right">Customer Support - <a href="contact.jsp">Contact us</a> | <a href="main.jsp">Home</a> |
        <?php if(is_null($_SESSION["username"])): ?> 
        <a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
        <?php else: ?>
        <a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing JavaScript and Java. JSP is short for Java Server Pages. Java and JavaScript are completely different languages.

The code you have shown above contains no Java, only PHP and JavaScript.

The .JSP file extension is for Java Server Pages and is not needed to run JavaScript. JavaScript can be run in PHP and HTMLfiles.

Comment: `if(session.getAttribute("username")==null)` is Java inside a JSP-page and there is no PHP.

Comment: you can use
if (session.getAttribute("Username") == null || session.getAttribute("Username").equals(""))
{
}
else
{
}

Comment: if (session.getAttribute("loggedIn") == null) {
     response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
} else if(session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals("admin")) {
     response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
} else if(!session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals("user")) {
     response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}

Answer (score 0):

You can write like below:

```
<?php if(is_null($_SESSION["username"])) {
    ?>
<a href="login.jsp">Login</a>
<?php } else {
        ?>
<a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
<?php } ?></td>
```